# Cannot setup 1 Gbit ethernet connection

Tags: connection, ethernet, realtek

I'm using Kubuntu 12.10. My router operate at 1Gbit connection with my other PC, I have 1Gbit ethernet card, cable is cat5e and can't setup 1Gbit ethernet connection. Only 100Mbit/s.

lspci|grep Ethernet

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 01)
```

sudo ethtool eth0

```
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                           drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

Kernel module for ethernet card is r8168. What's wrong?

Comment: What does `dmesg | grep -iEC2 "(eth0|link|r8168)"` give you?

Comment: This [article](http://www.rvdavid.net/how-to-get-gigabit-speeds-from-rtl81118168b-pci-express-gigabit-ethernet-controller-on-ubuntu-linux/) may be of interest.

Comment: @Steve-o *OP seems to be using the correct `r8168` driver.*

Comment: @gertvdijk the comments date to 2012 and still experiencing problems to ones surprise.

Comment: `dmesg | grep -iEC2 "(eth0|link|r8168)"` gives:
http://pastebin.com/zpjF1rVg
@Steve-o: I'm using r8168 kernel module, not r8169.